# Can I use java 8 in an mixed scala 2.10 / java project built by sbt?

Tags: java, scala, sbt, java-8, scala-java-interop

To what degree can I use java 8 in a mixed java / scala 2.10 sbt project?
Can I emit java 8 bytecode?  Use java 8 language features?  Or are there features in scala 2.11 that are necessary?  Is there an interop story?

Comment: http://scala-lang.org/news/2.11.1 : search for Java 8

Comment: I know that scala 2.11 has experimental java 8 support, but I'm asking about scala 2.10 (because of a project that can't be upgraded to scala 2.11).

Comment: So if you know that 2.11 has experimental support, it just stands to reason that 2.10 is going to have even less or even zero support.

Comment: What I.K. said. But the good news, at least, is that everything should run just fine. Lots of people use older Scalas with newer JREs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the `2.10.4` [Scala release notes](http://scala-lang.org/news/2.10.4):

> New ByteCode emitter based on ASM
>
> Can target JDK 1.5, 1.6 and 1.7
>
> Emits 1.6 bytecode by default
>
> Old 1.5 backend is deprecated

Also

> The official Scala 2.12 distribution will be built for Java 8 (and thus require it).

More background info of when you can expect to fully use Java 8:

> The Scala 2.11.x series targets Java 6, with (evolving) experimental >support for Java 8. In 2.11.1, Java 8 support is mostly limited to reading >Java 8 bytecode and parsing Java 8 source. Stay tuned for more complete >(experimental) Java 8 support. The next major release, 2.12, will most >likely target Java 8 by default.

And...

> Planned future Java 8-centric additions for Scala 2.12 include Java 8 >style closures, which will allow the Scala compiler to emit closure >classes (lambdas) just as you can with Java 8. There’s also planned lambda >syntax for SAM types. Again, in Java 8 fashion, this lets you instantiate >any type with one single abstract method by passing a lambda, improving >the user experiences for libraries written for Java 8 in Scala.