# ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.. IntelliJ and Scala

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I'm using Window 10, Scala 2.10.2, Spark 1.6.1, and Java 1.8.
Below is the code I'm trying to run.

```
import   org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import   org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object WordsCount {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkWordCount").setMaster("local[2]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val text = sc.textFile("shortTwitter.txt")
    val counts = text.flatMap(line=>line.split(" ")).map(word=>(word,1)).reduceByKey(_+_)
  counts.foreach(println)
}
}
```

and I got the following error.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7533 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.2.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program        Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\IdeaProjects\choi_jieun_assignment1\out\production\choi_jieun_assignment1;C:\scala\lib\jline.jar;C:\scala\lib\scalap.jar;C:\scala\lib\diffutils.jar;C:\scala\lib\akka-actors.jar;C:\scala\lib\scala-swing.jar;C:\scala\lib\scala-actors.jar;C:\scala\lib\scala-library.jar;C:\scala\lib\scala-partest.jar;C:\scala\lib\scala-reflect.jar;C:\scala\lib\scala-compiler.jar;C:\scala\lib\typesafe-config.jar;C:\scala\lib\scala-actors-migration.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-lang\scala-library\jars\scala-library-2.10.2.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-lang\scala-reflect\jars\scala-reflect-2.10.2.jar;C:\spark\lib\datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar;C:\spark\lib\datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar;C:\spark\lib\spark-1.6.1-yarn-shuffle.jar;C:\spark\lib\datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar;C:\spark\lib\spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar;C:\spark\lib\spark-examples-1.6.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.2.3\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain WordsCount

Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/spark/lib/spark-examples-1.6.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
16/09/14 16:03:21 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.6.1
16/09/14 16:03:22 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/09/14 16:03:22 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: Administrator
16/09/14 16:03:22 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: Administrator
16/09/14 16:03:22 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(Administrator); users with modify permissions: Set(Administrator)
16/09/14 16:03:23 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 50762.
16/09/14 16:03:23 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.<init>    (java.lang.String, akka.actor.ActorSystem$Settings, akka.event.EventStream,     akka.actor.Scheduler, akka.actor.DynamicAccess)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$2.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:77)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.createInstanceFor(DynamicAccess.scala:74)
at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$3.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:85)
at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$3.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:85)
at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:200)
at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.createInstanceFor(DynamicAccess.scala:85)
at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:546)
at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:111)
at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.org$apache$spark$util$AkkaUtils$$doCreateActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$startServiceOnPort$1.apply$mcVI$sp(Utils.scala:1988)
at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.startServiceOnPort(Utils.scala:1979)
at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.createActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:55)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:266)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:193)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:457)
at WordsCount$.main(WordsCount.scala:7)
at WordsCount.main(WordsCount.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
16/09/14 16:03:23 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.<init>(java.lang.String, akka.actor.ActorSystem$Settings, akka.event.EventStream, akka.actor.Scheduler, akka.actor.DynamicAccess)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$2.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:77)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.createInstanceFor(DynamicAccess.scala:74)
at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$3.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:85)
at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$3.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:85)
at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:200)
at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.createInstanceFor(DynamicAccess.scala:85)
at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:546)
at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:111)
at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.org$apache$spark$util$AkkaUtils$$doCreateActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$startServiceOnPort$1.apply$mcVI$sp(Utils.scala:1988)
at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.startServiceOnPort(Utils.scala:1979)
at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.createActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:55)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:266)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:193)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:457)
at WordsCount$.main(WordsCount.scala:7)
at WordsCount.main(WordsCount.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at             sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have been struggling for a couple of hours to solve this problem but couldn't figure out. Can someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: what is your akka version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing the [Java 7 JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) and you may have better luck. Although the release notes for Scala 2.10.2 seem to be missing, [2.10.4](http://scala-lang.org/news/2.10.4) doesn't support Java 8:

> New ByteCode emitter based on ASM
>
> Can target JDK 1.5, 1.6 and 1.7
>
> Emits 1.6 bytecode by default
>
> Old 1.5 backend is deprecated

...and even [2.11.x](http://scala-lang.org/news/2.11.1) only has experimental Java 8 support:

> The Scala 2.11.x series targets Java 6, with (evolving) experimental support for Java 8. In 2.11.1, Java 8 support is mostly limited to reading Java 8 bytecode and parsing Java 8 source. Stay tuned for more complete (experimental) Java 8 support. The next major release, 2.12, will most likely target Java 8 by default.

Also see: [Can I use java 8 in an mixed scala 2.10 / java project built by sbt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32126768/can-i-use-java-8-in-an-mixed-scala-2-10-java-project-built-by-sbt)

Comment: very true. 2.10.x and Java 8 don't go together that well. Also Spark 1.6.1 compiles to 2.10.x by default. In other words, if you want Java 8, you need to go to Scala 2.11.5+ and Spark 2.0.

Comment: thank you so much! I have been struggling with this so long and your tip works!!!!!!! really appreciate that

Comment: Happy to help :).  Being somewhat new to the Java ecosystem, I struggled with the same problem and wasted a few hours.